# where to store 10kb pieces of text in amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

These will be indexed and randomly accessed in a web app like SO questions. SimpleDB has a 1024-byte limit per attribute but you could use multiple attrs but sounds inelegant.

**Examples:** blog posts; facebook status messages; recipes  (in a blogging application; facebook-like application; recipe web site).

If I were to build such an application on Amazon AWS, where/how should I store the pieces of text?

Comment: Please expand on the meaning of "randomly accessed in a web app".

Comment: (edited) A good example is Stack Overflow questions, say under 10kb. If I had to build such a Stack Overflow application, where people would often view recent questions, search for old ones, favorite some to recall later. That's what I mean by randomly accessed in a web app.

Comment: @EricHammond, thanks for looking at the question. The original was typed on a smart phone and hence was brief. I have added more examples to the main question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With S3, you could put all the actual files in S3, then index them with Amazon RDS, or Postgres on Heroku, or whatever suits you at that time.

Also, you can get the client to download the multi kB text blurbs directly from S3, so your app could just deliver URLs to the messages, thereby creating a massively parallel server - even if the main server is just a single thread on one machine, constructing the page from S3 asset URLs. S3 could store all assets, like images, etc.

The advantages are big. This also solves backup, etc. And allows you to play with many indexing and searching schemes. Search could for instance be done using Google...

Comment: Thank you (upvoted). One catch is that S3 latency is rumored to be 100+ ms in best-case. The other catch, not a big problem, is to have control over who gets to see which piece of text. The latter is not a big problem because I could always have a private S3 bucket and serve off it conventinally. But the latency seems to be significant, not enough to be a show-stopper, but probably enough to require a memory cache infront of S3. It seems to be a choice between the expensive DynamoDB solution w/best latency; S3 w/medium; RDS w/scalability issues; or roll-my-own w/headaches. Sigh! Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget that you can with S3 mirror to different regions if you want. They also have cloud front. If you put 20 S3 links for assets into your web page, the browser will be downloading as many as it can in a highly optimized way in parallel, so it will only take a small amount of time to get all the assets, not 20*100ms. See https://client.spotdocuments.com/ and "testDrive' to see web pages with many S3 links in them to assets.

Comment: Yes, it is ideal for static non-permissioned stuff. But for pieces of text such as status messages or posts, I want to control who can access them and I want to log the accesses to keep track of popularity. So those benefits of S3 do not apply for my use case. Thanks for pointing them out since they do apply to other cases!

Comment: also, write latency is important too for non-static stuff. i am not sure what's the consistency situation for read-after-write with S3.

Comment: not clearly the right answer, but reasonable and the best among all the options so far. the read-after-write consistency is still an unknown. if somebody discovers what happens in that situation, please add a comment.

Comment: Read after write consistency is possible in all S3 regions except the default. Even in the default it usually works well. You could also mirror assets all over the world for speed. You have complete control over the assets - they will be in a private S3 bucket, and you can hand out 20 min time limited URLs. S3 supports logging. The latency problem is not likely to be an issue - if you try the spot docs client you can see the benefits of having a massively parallel asset server behind you. Don't spend time building a cache on the front until you know that is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you would want to look at Amazon RDS, running a relational database like MySQL in the cloud. A single DynamoDB read capacity unit can only (consistently) [read a 1kb-item](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_a_read/write_capacity_unit_How_do_I_estimate_how_many_read_and_write_capacity_units_I_need_for_my_application), that's probably not going to work for you.

Alternatively, you could store the text files in S3 and put pointers to these files in SimpleDB. It depends on a lot of factors which is going to be more cost-effective: how many files you add every day, how often these files are expected to change, how often they are requested, etc.

Personally, I think that using S3 would not be the best approach. If you store all questions and answers in separate text files, you're looking at a number of requests for displaying even a simple page. Let alone search, which would require you to fetch all the files from S3 and search through them. So for search, you need a database anyway.

You could use SDB for keeping an index but frankly, I would just use MySQL on Amazon RDS (there's a free two-month trial period right now, I think) where you can do all the nice things that relational databases can do, and which also offers support for full-text search. RDS should be able to scale up to huge numbers of visitors every day: you can easily scale up all the way to a High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large DB Instance with 68 GB of memory and 26 ECUs.

As far as I know, SO is also built on top of a relational database: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, you can also install MySQL on an EC2 instance and roll your own setup if you want to - you don't *have* to use RDS to run MySQL in the cloud. For small web sites, running MySQL on your own EC2 instance is probably cheaper, but on the other hand, setting it all up, creating back-ups, and all that will also take some time. And time is money ;)

Comment: Yes, the spirit question is cloud oriented, so the best candidate so far is S3 but I need to verify latency, granularity and cost for the granularity. I'd be more comfortable accepting your answer (after waiting for a few more) if you would emphasize the better cloud characteristics of S3 over RDS. I think RDS is scale constrained.

Comment: As far as the factors you asked: same use case as Stackoverflow questions and answers for how frequently created, accessed. The key is I don't know when my site will take off suddenly and I want to be ready without burning a hole in my pocket before it takes off.

Comment: Thank you for the updates! This is a pretty fundamental question and people might rely on the selected "right answer", so please bear with me if I take a while to decide and figure out the answer. The updates are definitely useful and I wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: Sure, I'm also keeping an eye on this to see what other people think :) Let us know how you get on!

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is might be what you want, there is even a forum use case in their documentation: [Example Tables and Data in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleTablesAndData.html)

Comment: upvoted; the limits page states a 64kb limit per item. dynamodb is expensive though. next best?

Comment: updated my post (it's 64kb per item but just 1kb for a single read/write capacity unit)

Comment: I can't tell you if it's expensive since you haven't provided any estimations on your data size and users, but the point is that DynamoDB is very scale-able. The cost is highly predictable in short AND long term and this is a big plus in the long run, whereas RDS  is less predictable.

Comment: Expensive - the biggest parameter is my wallet and I can tell you it is a micro ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is insufficient information in the question to provide a reasonable answer to "where should I store text that I'm going to use?"

Depending on how you build your application and what the requirements are for speed, redundancy, latency, volume, scalability, size, cost, robustness, reliability, searchability, modifiability, security, etc., the answer could be any of:

- Drop the text in files on an EBS volume attached to an instance.
- Drop the text into a MySQL or RDS database.
- Drop the text into a distributed file system spread across multiple instances.
- Upload the text to S3
- Store the text in SimpleDB
- Store the text in DynamoDB
- Cache the text in ElastiCache

There are also a number of variations on this like storing the master copy in S3, caching copies in ElastiCache and on the local disk, indexing it with specific keys in DynamoDB and making it searchable in Cloud Search.

Comment: '10kb pieces of text' not 'blobs of data'; further blob in the industry commonly means 'binary, *large* object' which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @agksmehx: Ok, I've updated my answer to say "text".  The answer remains the same.  There are a lot of potential places to store text and which one is best depends on a lot of factors that are not listed in the question.

Comment: also, I feel your list has things that the question would rule out; for instance, SimpleDB cannot store pieces longer than 1024-chars unless I program rather complicated code and work against its design. Other entries such as distributed file system seem a stretch for other reasons. While not best-written I do feel one can infer a lot of characteristics from the examples in the question (see for instance the other answers). I do appreciate the various cases, but they could be confusing for somebody other reader with a similar question.

Comment: in hindsight and comparing with the other answers, this was a pretty bad answer that includes some rather unwise options (ebs, distributed file system), a completely useless option simpledb that was pretty much ruled out in the first paragraph of the question itself, along with every other imaginable way. perhaps the intent was not to help get to a relevant answer but merely self-promote the author's knowledge of so many different ways. if the unwise options were not included i would have upvoted impressed with the knowledge; but the inclusion of the unwise options make a downvote necessary.